# Select one relations all fields & one or two from other relation on PIG JOIN, how?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
A = load '$input1' using pigStorage() AS (a,b,c,d,e)
B = load '$input2' using pigStorage() AS (a,b1,c1,d1,e1)
C = JOIN A by a, B by a; 
D = do something;
```

'D' should be of format (a,b,c,d,e,b1)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::a .. A::e, B::b AS b1;
```

Comment: So I dont have to do: "D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::a, A::b,A::c,A::d ,A::e, B::b AS b1; is it"?

A::a .. A::e takes care of everything between a to e?

Comment: It was added in Pig 0.9: http://hortonworks.com/blog/new-apache-pig-0-9-features-part-3-additional-features/